# I'm having an issue with pushing a Netbeans project to my remote Git repository

Tags: git, netbeans, ssh

I'm new to this Git stuff. I want to set up a Git repository on a remote Ubuntu server, that I can push and pull NetBeans projects/files from.  Basically, I'm using SSH to pull the project from the remote repository, make changes in NetBeans, then push those changes back to the remote Ubuntu server.

I don't wish to use GitHub because this project is to be worked on privately with a small team of 5, and we 1) don't want our stuff public and 2) Don't want to pay any money to use GitHub's private repositories.  There's a few other reasons, but nevertheless, we are not using GitHub.

I admit that I am ignorant in such matters, and don't even know if what I'm trying to do is feasible.

So, these are the steps I have taken:

1. Created a directory in Ubuntu server to hold my project/repository.
2. I downloaded a NetBeans project (a .zip file), and extracted it into the directory I created.  Don't know if it's relevant, but it's a PHP project.
3. I used `git init` to create the repository and then used `git add .` to add the contents of my project into the repository.
4. I used `git commit` to commit the changes to the repository.  I used `git status` and `git log` to confirm that the files were added to the repository.
5. I opened up NetBeans on my local machine (Windows), and I went to Team > Git > Clone.  In the menu that popped up,  for the Repository URL, I entered ssh://[my host]:[port]/path/to/repository/.git.
6. I entered username, password, and specified a destination folder for the cloned files and repository stuff, and clicked "Next".  I selected the branches (I think "master" was the only one available), then clicked "Next".  I selected a parent directory, gave the clone a name, and did all the stuff I was supposed to do on that screen, and clicked "Finish".
7. NetBeans confirmed that the clone was finished, and asked me if I wanted to open the project, and I clicked the option to open it.  Everything worked, I had a copy of the project on my local machine.

NOW, this is where stuff started getting confusing.

8. I added a new .php file to the project, and edited it.
9. I saved it, and then right-clicked my project in the Projects tab and went to Git > Add, to add the file.  Then I went to Git > Commit.
10. Then, I went to Team > Remote > Push, and pushed it back to the repository that I got it from.

When I went back to Ubuntu server and went to the directory where the repository is, I didn't see any changes.  I don't see the new .php file that I added to the project.

I'm not quite sure if I'm understanding the whole idea. Why don't I see any changes?

Comment: I've had problems using Netbeans to handle version control in the past. Have you tried using the command line to add-commit-push?

Comment: You could consider a Git account with BitBucket - I think that allows teams of up to five free of charge.

Comment: NonlinearFruit- I tried that and I still ran into the same problem.  halfer- does BitBucket allow private repositories?

Answer (score 0):

You only push the objects to the remote repository. You changes resides in object files in the .git of the remote repository.

Usually, a remote server only contains a .git and the underlying files, never an actually checked out project.

Try "git status" in the remote repository, you should see that the .php files you pushed is missing. Type "git checkout ." to make all project files reflect what is stored actually in the branch; it should be creating your .php file.

Check out [this guide](http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/create-a-new-git-remote-repository-from-some-local-files-or-local-git-repository/) on how to create a remote repository. The initial commit should actually come from your local machine and you shouldn't do it on the server.

Also, if you want github-like web-based functionnality, I recommend [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) which is a self hosted, open source, lightweight git service.

Comment: Thank you kindly, PoKo.  A checkout was exactly what I needed to do.